# setting up 2 tables in an SQLite database, anything wrong here?

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

I was wondering if anyone can see an error in how I am setting up 2 tables in an SQLite database?   Is what I am doing here wrong?  I have never done more than one table for sqlite.

my logcat stacktrace shows error is  Index 0 requested, with a size of 0,  i am trying to eliminate any problem with how I set up 2 tables in one database for SQLite as the cause for this error, any ideas?

here is the code shown below where 2 tables are created

```
 public class Database {

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "allert_database";
    public static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "allert_table";
    public static final String DATABASE_TABLE2 = "allert_table2";
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String _ID = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_SENTENCE = "sentance";
    public static final String KEY_DESCRIPTION = "description";

  //create table DATABASE_TABLE (_ID integer primary key, Content text not null);
    private static final String SCRIPT_CREATE_TABLE =
        "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" + _ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +  
        KEY_SENTENCE + " TEXT);";

    // create the second table DATABASE_TABLE2
    private static final String SCRIPT_CREATE_TABLE2 =
      "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE2 + " (" + _ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +  
      KEY_DESCRIPTION + " TEXT);";

    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;
    SQLiteHelper sqLiteHelper;
    Context context;

    public Database(Context c){
          context = c;
         }


public class SQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

          public SQLiteHelper(Context context, String name,
            CursorFactory factory, int version) {
           super(context, name, factory, version);
          }

          // onCreate of the SQLiteOpenhelper only called if the database does not already exist
          @Override
          public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
           db.execSQL(SCRIPT_CREATE_TABLE);
           db.execSQL(SCRIPT_CREATE_TABLE2);
          }

          @Override
           public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
           db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
           db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE2);
             onCreate(db);
          }

         }
```

EDIT:  just for fun i added here the query method where the stacktrace says the error is:

```
              // get sentence from table one
         public String getSentenceFromTableOne(int rowNum){
             String status = " ";
             String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_SENTENCE};
             String selection = _ID + " = '" + rowNum + "';";
             Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, 
                        selection, null, null, null, null);
             if (cursor != null){
                    cursor.moveToFirst();
             }
             status = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_SENTENCE));
             cursor.close();
            return status;

         }
```

and here is the method below from main activity that calls the database query method shown above from the database class

```
 public String getSentenceTableOne(int enterNum){
    Database db = new Database(context);
    db.openToWrite();
    String returnStr = db.getSentenceFromTableOne(enterNum);
    db.close();
    return returnStr;
}
```

EDIT 2:   i will investigate further,  however for completeness i have added here my instantiation of sqlite helper class,  or how it was done

```
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;
    SQLiteHelper sqLiteHelper;
    Context context;

    public Database(Context c){
          context = c;
         }

    public void openToRead() throws android.database.SQLException {
          sqLiteHelper = new SQLiteHelper(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
          sqLiteDatabase = sqLiteHelper.getReadableDatabase();
         }

    public void openToWrite() throws android.database.SQLException {
          sqLiteHelper = new SQLiteHelper(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
          sqLiteDatabase = sqLiteHelper.getWritableDatabase();
         }
```

FINAL EDIT:  the original reason for asking the question, if there were any problems with my implementation of more than one table in the database.  this was answered,  however I found that the real error was in calling the wrong method from the main class,  I was calling the update method in the database class from the insert method of the main class.  that is why no new information was being inserted into the database.

Comment: Seems OK to me. Error looks like a problem in your query?

Comment: i just edited adding the query method form the database class and the method that calls the query method from the main class to the posted code

Comment: Do you definitely have data in there? You are expecting 1 row back?

Comment: good idea i am going to check that with ADB pull of the db file.  it should be there as i used an add new row method to row 1,  and did a query later to row 1 to get the stored info in it.

Comment: i just looked at the db file using the emulator and it is empty.  not what i expected

Comment: Without knowing the history of your development process it's hard to comment any further :)

Comment: Actually, where are you instantiating sqLiteHelper?

Comment: yes i did instantiated it in the openToRead() and openToWrite() methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the cursor is empty. So `.moveToFirst()` doesn't work because there is no first.

Instead of just

```
if (cursor != null)
```

Try

```
if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount > 0)
```

Make sure you actually have data in there. If you do, and it's not showing, take a look at your query closely.

Also, instead of creating your selection like this:

```
String selection = _ID + " = '" + rowNum + "';";
```

I would use variables like so:

```
String selection = _ID + "= ?";
String [] args = new String[] {String.valueOf(rowNum)};
...
Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, 
                    selection, args, null, null, null);
```

This helps prevents problems with String concatenation screwing up your query.

Edit: Also make sure you are also actually instantiating sqLiteHelper somewhere, I assume that's not all your code.

Comment: thank you for your response,  i will check that and make sure the sqlite helper class is instantiating correctly,  kind of getting closer to where the problem is.

Comment: it is looking like the fact that the database has two tables is not the problem. it is something else

Comment: @Kevik Agrre, it's not the two tables causing the problem. BTW I usually instantiate it when I instantiate my equivalent of your `Database` class.

Comment: It is good to know that my code for two tables looks OK,  so that was the main reason for asking the question.   but i just found out what the problem was,  my insert method in the main class for inserting a new row was calling the update method in the database class!!!!!  that is why it was not working.